# Automatic geocoding using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing

I'm trying create a VBA script that will let me geocode my address database. I've been working on this script for a few days and I think there comes a time when I have to ask experts for some advice.
So, I want the script to access a google maps url and find latitude and longitude values. I managed to extract that information from a local XML document, but I cannot do so using an XML read from the google maps server. The code that worked for me is as follows:

```
Sub XMLread()
Dim odc As DOMDocument
Dim nde As IXMLDOMNode
Dim lat As IXMLDOMElement
Dim url As String

Set odc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
url = "C:\~path~\address.xml"
odc.Load (url)

For Each nde In odc.SelectNodes("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location")
    Set lat = nde.SelectSingleNode("lat")
    Debug.Print lat.Text
Next
End Sub
```

What this code does is it opens an xml file, finds the value for "lat" and prints it in the debug window. I'm planning to place the results in a spreadsheet, but that's not gonnna be a problem. The problem is with extracting the data straight from the server. I use the following code:

```
Sub XMLerverRead()
Dim odc As DOMDocument
Dim nde As IXMLDOMNode
Dim lat As IXMLDOMElement
Dim url As String
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+Santa+Clara,+California+95014&sensor=false"

Set odc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
odc.async = False
odc.Load (url)

For Each nde In odc.SelectNodes("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location")
    Set lat = nde.SelectSingleNode("lat")
    Debug.Print lat.Text
Next
End Sub
```

And the above code does not return anything, not even an error. Could you please help me out and tell me how can I fix this code? Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm a VBA newbie, but I've done a good research on this issue.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: What the... Actually, I copied it to a new worksheet and it worked. But it returns two values - 37.3317055 and 37.3318200. It's probably because of the For loop which is executed twice. Can I get rid of that loop somehow?

Comment: Sure you can.  Use the Xpath to define exaclty which one you want.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to replace that For Each with a single line of code, but I didn't manage to do so - the only thing I got were the errors :)
Hence I think I'll live it as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub XMLerverRead()
   Dim odc As DOMDocument
   Dim url As String
   Dim lat As String

   url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+Santa+Clara,+California+95014&sensor=false"

   Set odc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
   odc.async = False
   odc.Load (url)

   If odc Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Odc is not loaded with the Xml."

   Else
      lat= vbNullString       'This is to assure that the variable lat has no value.'       
      On Error Resume Next    'We dont want to show the user a system msgbox if the node does not exist'
      lat = odc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location/lat").Text
      On Error Goto 0

      If lat=vbNullString Then   'Here you can show the user some useful info or do something with your code instead'
         MsgBox "There is no Latitude value for a 'ROOFTOP' node in the given XML"
      End If
   End If        

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

I made some modification on the code to help answer your questions.

Note:
I used node 'ROOFTOP' for the sake of the example.  If you are fine with the first lat value found, you could use any of the following option.

```
 odc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat")
 odc.SelectSingleNode("//lat")
```

The more you read about Xpath the easier it will make your task.  Important is to note that VBA works only with Xpath 1.0 (Xpath 2 is not supported).

Comment: Actually, I just started getting an error - "Object variable or With block variable not set". The debugger highlights the line in which I assign value to lat: lat = odc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location/lat").Text

Comment: If I want to assign the last line of your code to "lat" variable do I have to declare that variable in some special way? Or do I have to use "Set"?

Comment: About the error.  It could be because there was no 'geometry' node with a 'location_Type' equal to 'ROOFTOP'.  In that case 'SelectSingleNode' will return `Nothing` and therefore the error.  It could also be because `odc` was not loaded with the XML.  Check both possibilities.